# convert comma separated list in text file into columns in bash

Tags: bash, list, parsing, text, transpose

I've managed to extract data (from an html page) that goes into a table, and I've isolated the columns of said table into a text file that contains the lines below:

```
[30,30,32,35,34,43,52,68,88,97,105,107,107,105,101,93,88,80,69,55],
[28,6,6,50,58,56,64,87,99,110,116,119,120,117,114,113,103,82,6,47],
[-7,,,43,71,30,23,28,13,13,10,11,12,11,13,22,17,3,,-15,-20,,38,71],
[0,,,3,5,1.5,1,1.5,0.5,0.5,0,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,1,0.5,0,-0.5,-0.5,2.5]
```

Each bracketed list of numbers represents a column. What I'd like to do is turn these lists into actual columns that I can work with in different data formats. I'd also like to be sure to include that blank parts of these lists too (i.e., "[,,,]")

This is basically what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
30 28 -7  0
30  6    
32  6     
35 50 43  3
34 58 71  5
43 56 30  1.5
52 64 23  1
 .  .  .  .
 .  .  .  .
 .  .  .  .
```

I'm parsing data from a web page, and ultimately planning to make the process as automated as possible so I can easily work with the data after I output it to a nice format.

Anyone know how to do this, have any suggestions, or thoughts on scripting this?

Comment: Why is your input in that particular format? Are you creating it from some other language?

Comment: Yes (to your 2nd question), I pulled it from a web page's source code using python. It seemed potentially easier to use bash to parse that text output.

Comment: Do you have the data in python data structures (dictionaries or lists)? If so, it could be easier (and faster) to stay in python..

Comment: Yea, sorry for the delay. I had to rework my end-goal, and I think it will be easier/more efficient in python. I'll be back with details, as the solution may be on this page now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk based solution:

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/\[|\]/, ""); for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i]=a[i] ? a[i] OFS $i: $i}
      END {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print a[i]}' file
30 28 -7 0
30 6  
32 6  
35 50 43 3
34 58 71 5
43 56 30 1.5
52 64 23 1
..........
..........
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have your lists in python, just do it in python:

```
l=[["30", "30", "32"], ["28","6","6"], ["-7", "", ""], ["0", "", ""]]
for i in zip(*l):
  print "\t".join(i)
```

produces

```
30      28      -7      0
30      6
32      6
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, but it works only for file with 4 lines:

```
$ paste \
<(sed -n '1{s,\[,,g;s,\],,g;s|,|\n|g;p}' t) \
<(sed -n '2{s,\[,,g;s,\],,g;s|,|\n|g;p}' t) \
<(sed -n '3{s,\[,,g;s,\],,g;s|,|\n|g;p}' t) \
<(sed -n '4{s,\[,,g;s,\],,g;s|,|\n|g;p}' t)
30  28  -7  0
30  6       
32  6       
35  50  43  3
34  58  71  5
43  56  30  1.5
52  64  23  1
68  87  28  1.5
88  99  13  0.5
97  110 13  0.5
105 116 10  0
107 119 11  0.5
107 120 12  0.5
105 117 11  0.5
101 114 13  0.5
93  113 22  1
88  103 17  0.5
80  82  3   0
69  6       -0.5
55  47  -15 -0.5
        -20 2.5

        38  
        71
```

Updated: or another version with preprocessing:

```
$ sed 's|\[||;s|\][,]\?||' t >t2
$ paste \
<(sed -n '1{s|,|\n|g;p}' t2) \
<(sed -n '2{s|,|\n|g;p}' t2) \
<(sed -n '3{s|,|\n|g;p}' t2) \
<(sed -n '4{s|,|\n|g;p}' t2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If a file named `data` contains the data given in the problem (exactly as defined above), then the following bash command line will produce the output requested:

```
$ sed -e 's/\[//' -e 's/\]//' -e 's/,/ /g' <data | rs -T
```

Example:

```
cat data
[30,30,32,35,34,43,52,68,88,97,105,107,107,105,101,93,88,80,69,55],
[28,6,6,50,58,56,64,87,99,110,116,119,120,117,114,113,103,82,6,47],
[-7,,,43,71,30,23,28,13,13,10,11,12,11,13,22,17,3,,-15,-20,,38,71],
[0,,,3,5,1.5,1,1.5,0.5,0.5,0,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,1,0.5,0,-0.5,-0.5,2.5]

$ sed -e 's/[//' -e 's/]//' -e 's/,/ /g' <data | rs -T
30    28    -7    0
30    6     43    3
32    6     71    5
35    50    30    1.5
34    58    23    1
43    56    28    1.5
52    64    13    0.5
68    87    13    0.5
88    99    10    0
97    110   11    0.5
105   116   12    0.5
107   119   11    0.5
107   120   13    0.5
105   117   22    1
101   114   17    0.5
93    113   3     0
88    103   -15   -0.5
80    82    -20   -0.5
69    6     38    2.5
55    47    71
```

Comment: I've got `command not found: rs` In which package it resides?

Comment: It is a standard FreeBSD/Linux/MacOSX command:  see http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/1/rs/ -- you may need to do "yum search rs" and then install the right package.

Comment: I'm not sure that this command is standard. At least it absent in default Ubuntu installation and I can't find it because `apt-cache search rs` returned more than 16k lines..

Comment: rs has been a standard on FreeBSD, Solaris, MacOSX for a long time.  People using Ubuntu have to work a little harder to have the same features as the other distributions, not just for "rs".  See this article: http://www.danielmiessler.com/blog/categories/linux.   See this link especially: http://www.danielmiessler.com/blog/collection-of-less-commonly-used-unix-commands

Comment: Here is a pointer for Ubuntu's "rs" - http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/rs.1.html